# where can I get the NEW Hardware? to make profit

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware

Currently 2015 mid-October, how can I get the NEW hardware to actually make profit, after paying the electricity bill, ventilation, the cooling and all the extra cost?
I'm not aiming for $100 per day, but just anything above 3 Dollars per day will be fine. I've use the calculator websites to check the available chips in the market and after I input the hash rate and the Watt and the electricity cost, (which I happen to have for only 10 cents not 15), I still can't make profit.
am I doing something wrong or it's really getting impossible to make money out of mining now. thanks for any help..

Comment: It's actually pretty much always been like that (for the reason David mentions). Especially if you have to include a lead time of several months for the hardware to arrive.

Comment: related: [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not doing anything wrong. If it was easy to make a profit, everyone would do it, raising the difficulty, and bringing the profit to zero. Only those with the lowest cost of electricity, the lowest cost of capital, and who can get the best deals on high-end ASIC miners can make a profit. And even then, only by taking the risk that the difficulty or price will not change in ways they didn't expect.